# why "this" is not found in module while button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing one issue while creating module .I am appending a list item on button click but my object property is undefined why ? `this.config` ??

here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/5hrcwj8g/

on button click

I am calling this function

```
Nav.prototype.addItems = function() {
        console.log(this.config)
        this.config.$navigationPanel.append('<li>tens</li>');
    };
```

this line give undefined why ?

```
console.log(this.config)
```

suggest better solution

```
var Nav = (function() {
    function Nav() {
        this.config = {
            $navigationPanel: $('#navigationPanel ul'),
            $addItems: $('#adItems')
        };
    }
    Nav.prototype.init = function() {
    console.log(this.config)
        this.attachHandlers();
    };
    Nav.prototype.addItems = function() {
        console.log(this.config)
        this.config.$navigationPanel.append('<li>tens</li>');
    };
    Nav.prototype.attachHandlers = function() {
        this.config.$addItems.on('click', this.addItems);
    };
    return Nav;
})();
$(function() {
    var n =  new Nav();
    n.init();
});
```

Comment: @ImAtWar this and $(this) are same. one being native other jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your `attachHandlers` function as follows -

```
Nav.prototype.attachHandlers = function() {
    this.config.$addItems.on('click', this.addItems.bind(this));
};
```

Since `addItems` is a event callback function, it doesn't get the `this` reference to the Nav class. By binding `this` reference of Nav class while assigning click event handler the `addItems` function gets access to Nav class reference.

Answer (score 0):

`this` always points to the caller of the function. It's easy to assume that in your case, since `addItems` belongs to `Nav` that `this` will point to `Nav` but that's not the case.

There is a way to make `Nav` available in your `addItems` method and that's through hard binding. When you hard binding the `this` reference, nothing can change it. `this` will always point to whatever object it pointed when you bound it.

You can hard-bind `this` in any function with any object using the `.bind()` method. Check it out on [MDN][1]

So in your case you need to rewrite your `attachHandlers` method like this:

```
Nav.prototype.attachHandlers = function() {
    this.config.$addItems.on('click', this.addItems.bind(this));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//this will definitely work and your item will be added   

 var Nav = function() {    
                  this.config = {               
                      $navigationPanel: $('#navigationPanel ul'),
                      $addItems: $('#adItems')
                    }             
                };
                Nav.prototype = function() {

                    var init =function(){                         
                      this.attachHandlers();  
                    }
                  var addItems = function() {
                    this.config.$navigationPanel.append('<li>tens</li>');
                  };
                  var attachHandlers = function() {
                    console.log(this)
                    this.config.$navigationPanel.append('<li>tens</li>');
                    this.config.$addItems.on('click', this.addItems.bind(this));
                  };
                  return {
                    init : init,
                    attachHandlers:attachHandlers,
                    addItems:addItems           
                  }
                }();
                $(function() {
                    var n =  new Nav();
                    n.init();
                });
```